# drdb giving error when being restarted in the configuration process

Tags: high-availability, ubuntu-18.04, drbd, heartbeat

I am setting up HA following this tutorial https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-drbd-heartbeat-high-availability/ but when i try to `sudo systemctl restart drbd` after `sudo drbdadm create-md r0` it fails to restart and gives me error `IP 10.130.199.61 not found on this host.`

my hosts file is:

```
10.130.199.60 node1 node1.domain
10.130.199.61 node2 node2.domain
```

and the r0.res is:

```
global {
usage-count no;
}
resource r0 {
protocol C;
startup {
degr-wfc-timeout 60;
}
disk {
}
syncer {
rate 100M;
}
net {
cram-hmac-alg sha1;
shared-secret "aBcDeF";
}
on node1 {
device /dev/drbd0;
disk /dev/sdb1;
address 10.130.199.60:7789;
meta-disk internal;
}
on node2 {
device /dev/drbd0;
disk /dev/sdb1;
address 10.130.199.61:7789;
meta-disk internal;
}
}
```

Is there anyone who can help resolve the issue?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you define that IP 10.130.199.61 in your /etc/ha.d/haresources file? Is heartbeat running on each of the nodes?

DRBD is trying to bind to this IP, so it needs to be configured on one of your nodes. heartbeat will take care of this.

Please be aware that you're following a guide for ubuntu 16 while you seem to be using ubuntu 18.

Comment: thank you for the answer, the issue is resolved.
There was a strange behavior that was caused by hyper-V.
Making new VM's that are "generation 2" instead of 1 solved it.